# Mean-value theorem for nonsmooth functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be convex and Lipschitz continuous, and let $\partial f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightrightarrows \mathbb{R}^n$ denote the generalized gradient/subdifferential of $f$ (which is upper semi-continuous, taking nonemtpy, compact and convex values). Is it possible to rewrite/or lower bound
\begin{equation}
\langle x - \tilde{x}, \xi(x) - \xi(\tilde{x}) \rangle,
\end{equation}
where $\xi(y) \in \partial f(y)$, in terms of a "quadratic form" in $(x - \tilde{x})$? Does there exist sth like a MVT
\begin{equation}
\xi(x) - \xi(\tilde{x}) \in S([\cdot])(x - \tilde{x}),
\end{equation}
for some set $S$ that might involve second-order derivatives, e.g. coderivatives?

Comment: Considering the one dimensional case, I am skeptical. The first derivative can be any increasing function. The amount by which it grows on an interval is not related to the derivative unless we assume it to be differentiable everywhere.